# Is there a way to collect address info via Paypal donation IPNs

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've got a scenario where I need to collect address details from Paypal when a user donates to a site.  From what I can tell in the Paypal Sandbox those details aren't returned via IPN or PDT when the transaction is related to a donation.

Is there something I'm missing like an account setting or paypal variable that can make this possible?

At the moment I'm using a Buy Now option as below which does return address details:

```
input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"
```

Simply changing the cmd to donation and the address info stops coming in via IPN:

```
input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the address is given on donations. Your best bet is to call it a donation in the title & then send it still as an xclick. Change the displayed button image to a donation button, but use an xclick instead of _donation. I believe that's the only possible way.